# Mapping of single container object to list with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a structure with a single top level node `RootSource` with child objects `Source` needing to be mapped to a list of child objects `List<Destination>`.

```
    public class RootSource
    {
        public List<Source> Sources { get; set; }
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public string SourceData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        public string DestinationData { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what I would like to achive:

```
    [Test]
    public void MapperTest()
    {
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                .ForMember(x => x.DestinationData, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.SourceData));
            cfg.CreateMap<RootSource, List<Destination>>()
                ???;
        })
        .CreateMapper();

        var rootSource = new RootSource
        {
            Sources = new List<Source> {
                new Source { SourceData = "A" },
                new Source { SourceData = "B" },
            }
        };

        var destinations = mapper.Map<List<Destination>>(rootSource);

        Assert.AreEqual(2, destinations.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(rootSource.Sources[0].SourceData, destinations[0].DestinationData);
        Assert.AreEqual(rootSource.Sources[1].SourceData, destinations[1].DestinationData);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found ONE solution, but it feels less than ideal, relaying on use of converter. Is there some less complex way of resolving this with AutoMapper?

```
public class RootSourceToListDestinationConverter : ITypeConverter<RootSource, List<Destination>>
{
    public List<Destination> Convert(RootSource rootSource, List<Destination> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var result = new List<Destination>();

        if (rootSource != null)
        {
            foreach (var source in rootSource.Sources)
            {
                result.Add(context.Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

with the addition of this mapper entry:

```
cfg.CreateMap<RootSource, List<Destination>>().ConvertUsing<RootSourceToListDestinationConverter>();
```